# Two TiKZ figures side-by-side inside a wrapfig environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, wrapfig

I am trying to place two tikz figures side-by-side inside wrapfig environment.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
    \tikzset{
        -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
        state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
        point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
        bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
        el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =1cm and 1.3cm]
                \node (X0) [label=left:{$X$},point];
                \node (Z0) [label=left:{$Z$},below of = X0,point];
                \node (Y0) [label=left:{$Y$},below of = Z0,point];
            
                \path (X0) edge (Z0);
                \path (Z0) edge (Y0);
                \path[bidirected] (X0) edge[bend left=50] (Z0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Unidentifiable}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =1cm and 1.3cm]
                \node (X0) [label=left:{$X$},point];
                \node (Z0) [label=left:{$Z$},below of = X0,point];
                \node (Y0) [label=left:{$Y$},below of = Z0,point];
            
                \path (X0) edge (Z0);
                \path (Z0) edge (Y0);
                \path[bidirected] (X0) edge[bend left=50] (Y0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Identifiable}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Write me}
    \label{fig:ID_examples}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Predictably this does not work as the subfigures are stacked rather than side-by-side. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Now the subfigures are side-by-sude.

- In a pure `standalone` document `wrapfigure` doesn't work. At least you need to add `varwidth` option.
- A `wrapfig` should be inserted before paragraph in which you like to be.
- For use of the `subfigure` you need to add to preamble `subcaption` package.
- Widths of `subfigure should be less than half of` wrapfigure`
- For nice placement of subcaptions you need to increase `wrapfigure` width (if you use `article` documentclass).

A MWE, using `article` document class, with side by side subfigures in `wrapfigure˙ is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}
\tikzset{auto,
            > = Latex,
                semithick,
node distance = 12mm and 22mm,
 state/.style = {ellipse, draw, minimum width = 7mm},
 point/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
                 node contents={}},
        }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.44\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (X0) [label=left:{$X$},point];
                \node (Z0) [label=left:{$Z$},below=of X0, point];
                \node (Y0) [label=left:{$Y$},below=of Z0, point];
            %
                \path   (X0) edge (Z0)
                        (Z0) edge (Y0);
                \path[<->, dashed] (X0) edge[bend left=50] (Z0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Unidentifiable}
    \end{subfigure}
    %
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (X0) [label=left:{$X$},point];
                \node (Z0) [label=left:{$Z$},below=of X0,point];
                \node (Y0) [label=left:{$Y$},below=of Z0,point];

                \path   (X0) edge (Z0)
                        (Z0) edge (Y0);
                \path[<->, dashed] (X0) edge[bend left=50] (Y0);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Identifiable}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Write me}
    \label{fig:ID_examples}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right apologies. Next time, if you're going to comment on the MWE/question formatting and not provide a solution, add it as a comment to the question to reduce clutter.

Comment: @Astrid, ups, you like to have subfigures in paralel. Corrected now.

Comment: I am sorry I don't follow, is yours a solution? Because you've posted a screenshot which is identical to mine but I am looking to have them side-by-side within a wrapfig environment.

Comment: @Astrid, your document is not compilable, so at correcting it to workable form I overlooked that subfigures should be side-by-side. Now they are, i.e. answer provide what hat you after.

Comment: Thank you, answer accepted.